# Magento: Order first canceled and then complete

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

What happens when one order first canceled and after that the order is set to complete?
I use a payment provider to handle my payments for credit cards and direct debit.

Here is a example screenshot from this special order:

http://upimage.us/server/php/files/Bildschirmfoto%202014-08-29%20um%2011.29.56.png

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sue what your question is, but the flows are for instance:

- Place Order -> Invoice -> Ship All -> Complete
- Place Order -> Invoice -> Refund All -> Complete
- Place Order -> Cancel All -> Cancel